# Count likes of each user using two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, the first one is `POSTS`that has three fields (`post_id`, `user_id`, `text`) the second table is `LIKES` has two fields (`user_id`, `post_id`) `likes.user_id` is the id of the user who liked the post.

Now I want to query the database and get the count of likes (distance) of each user to another. Meaning I'd get a result of three fields, four with the index (I'm not too worried about it for now):

```
User 1 | User 2 | count(INT) | index
-------------------------------------
User_a | User_b |     45     | ab
User_c | User_n |     53     | cn
User_b | User_a |     38     | ba
```

I tried using something like this, but I'm not always getting an accurate number of likes. Also, I'm getting some data redundancy.

```
SELECT likes.user_id, posts.user_id,
COUNT(likes.post_id)
from posts, likes
WHERE posts.post_id = likes.post_id
GROUP BY posts.user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(likes.post_id)
```

**I'm a MySQL rookie, so excuse any errors!, Thank you for any help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT likes.user_id, posts.user_id,
COUNT(DISTINCT likes.post_id) --<<changed
from posts
INNER JOIN likes ON posts.post_id = likes.post_id --<<changed
GROUP BY likes.user_id, posts.user_id --<<changed
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT likes.post_id) --<<changed
```

I suspect the "data redundancy" may be coming from your group by clause. While MySQL does allow you to write queries that don't comply with SQL standards in this clause, it is important to always specify all the non-aggregating columns. (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html for details of the non-standard syntax MySQL allows, but which should not be used.)

The other item of change is use of DISTINCT within the count function. Without access to your tables I don't know if that is required but it could address the accuracy issue you state.

Finally. Please stop using a commas separated list of tables as your from clause. This is no longer good practice and you should follow ANSI style join syntax which is more specific and easier to maintain.

Comment: Thank you so much, I though we cannot use DISTINCT with Count, and only with SELECT!!
But unfortunately, I'm getting more data redundancy now. I think there is a small thing that we both couldn't catch yet.

Comment: You have not really described or defined your problem fully. Consider providing sample source data from both tables plus your expected result. From those rlements a solution can be determined. By the way add the data to you question

Comment: I'd love to share some data from the database, but it's a very big one. I'll do my best to use what you gave me, and wait for more solutions from the folks here. Thank you so much!

Comment: **sample** does not need to be large. just large enough to demonstrate the problem, it only needs the columns required for the specific problem too, so names etc are not needed. quite often samples are manually prepared and so are the expected results, which, ideally, are derived directly from the sample.

Comment: by the way you might want to explain what YOU mean by "data redundancy" in the result because the group by I proposed must by definition produce unique rows

Comment: You actually got it perfectly right, I made a mistake thinking that I shouldn't have the same `user_id` to show up more than once in the left column. Thank you so much for your help!